# How to get multitouch support in Bluestacks?

Tags: android

I was playing The Room on Bluestacks, and the game requires features of a real android device such as multitouch, tilt, shake and swipe. Although the first level was quite simple, and required only swiping, I finished it quickly. But the second chapter has many functions like tilt and multitouch. I don't know what it has in the third chapter as this game has 5 chapters in all, and I was stuck at the chapter 2 multitouch part where I have to swipe to switches at the same time. So is there a way to complete it?

Comment: If you're using an emulator, chances are pretty good things like this happen.  That said, perhaps the emulator uses some creative tricks to try to emulate tilting and multitouch.

Comment: I was able to mimic tilting by creating a config file by Aurora 2 and it worked great. But it doesn't have anything from multitouch and I don't know it's commands.

Comment: @Hunter How did you mimic the tilt and multi touch..Found any way to do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is question about android emulator

Answer (score 2):

I actually opened a thread on their forum about this. While there are 3rd party options, as mentioned by lucky (I personally couldn't be bothered messing around trying to get these to work), there is currently no support within Bluestacks itself.

[Bluestacks forum thread](https://bluestacks.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208242363-Multi-touch)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a post from the [xda-developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=24300942&postcount=32),

> If you want experience multitouch on bluestack but your windows not
>   have multitouch screen install Droidmote Client on your phone (free),
>   install Droidmote Server for windows on your windows. For
>   example, in google maps you can zoom in out rotate with two finger etc.

With your android phone, with one application called [DroidMote Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videomap.droidmoteclient), you can control another android Phone or Tablet, a Windows pc or a Linux pc, on wich you have installed [DroidMote Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videomap.droidmoteserver.).

**Features:**

Remote Mouse:

[✔] Remote Multitouch Touchpad

[✔] Two Fingers Scroll Zoom Rotate

[✔] Remote Keyboard

[✔] Remote Mediaplayer

[✔] Remote Dpad

[✔] Remote Multitouch Gamepad

[✔] Remote Control with accelerometer

[✔] Two virtual analog stick on screen

[✔] Touch emulation allows you to map buttons and analog sticks to the screen. Play all your favourite games with full analog support, even those without built-in controller support!

[✔] TouchMouse for games that not support a real mouse

[✔] Voice dictation with android keyboard

[✔] Gesture typing with android 4.2 keyboard

Further more information on [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1292627).

Answer (score 0):

I did the following, there is an option in the keyboard, where it says swipe, if you add the swipe function and for example Left is A, then Right is D, and press both at the same time it does the 2 finger swipe, but it only works on both sides and up and down. I got my issue resolved like that.